# Laravel - .TXT file Being Converted to .BIN on Upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm not quite sure where to look, so I can't even tell if this is an issue with the server or with the Laravel project itself, but on one of my models, if I upload a `.TXT` file attached to a record, it shows up on the server as a `.BIN` file.

There isn't really anything to the upload controller action itself:

```
if($request->paymentAttachment){
    $payment->attachment = Storage::putFile('public/payments', $request->file('paymentAttachment'));
}
```

So I'm not sure where the conversion might be happening. If there are any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned on [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem), the file's extension type is determined by examining the file's MIME type. 
So check your uploaded TXT file MIME or try to put file by a specefied name and extension like this :

`Storage::putFileAs('public/payments', $request->file('paymentAttachment'), 'yourfilename.txt');`